# Register user to QuickBlox Users from android

Tags: java, android, quickblox

I'm trying to use QuickBlox in my android application, I read the guide and imported the sample and everything worked fine.

I changed a few things that user can login using EditText for username and another for password.. and it worked fine.

But now I want to add a Register Button that makes the user able to register new account.. I don't know how to do that.. Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the solution :

```
QBUsers.signUp(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
        public void onSuccess(QBUser result, Bundle params) {
            // success
        }

        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    SplashActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage(
                    "register errors: " + errors)
                    .create().show();
        }
    });
```