# Cannot signin to QuickBlox in Android

Tags: android, quickblox

I am new to `QuickBlox`. After going through the tutorial I have done the following to signup a new user into `QuickBlox`. The problem is that I am getting the following errors:

```
 1. {"errors":["Token is required"]}
 2. STATUS : 201
```

I referred to the following question [Register user to QuickBlox Users from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804303/register-user-to-quickblox-users-from-android)    but it didn't help.

My Codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
Button sign_up;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit("XxxXX", "XXXXXX",
            "XXXXXX");
    sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_up);
    sign_up.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.sign_up:
        QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final QBUser user = new QBUser("user1", "123456789");
                user.setExternalId("45345");

                user.setFullName("User1");
                user.setPhone("123456789");

                QBUsers.signUp(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(List<String> errors) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession arg0, Bundle arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get this error? It's not clear from your code example

Also the right way to create a user is inside this callback:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(QBSession arg0, Bundle arg1)
```

not this

```
@Override
public void onSuccess()
```